# How parent component pass HTML to child component in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

> How parent component pass multiple ng-templates to child component?

Example the Parent component contains multiple ng-templates:

```
<app-childcomponent>
    <ng-template>Item A</ng-template>
    <ng-template>Item B</ng-template>
    ...
</app-childcomponent>
```

Child component needs to receive the ng-templates from parent and put inside `app-menu`:

```
 <app-menu>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
 </app-menu>
```

So it will look something like this in the Child component:

```
<app-menu>    
   <ng-template>Item 1</ng-template>     //having trouble sending this to app-menu from parent
   <ng-template>Item 2</ng-template>     //having trouble sending this to app-menu from parent
<app-menu>
```

but it seems like the `ng-content` is empty causing `app-menu` not getting the **`multiple ng-templates`**.

```
 <app-menu>
    //empty
 </app-menu>
```

**What have I tried?**

1. I have tried passing the template via @input. `<app-childcomponent [myTemplate]="myTemplate"></child-component>`
2. Template outlet. Result: Child component unable to get`ng-templates`.

Parent html:

```
<app-childcomponent>
    <ng-template>Item 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template>Item 2</ng-template>
</app-childcomponent>
```

Parent class:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) templateRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Child html:

```
<app-menu>
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></ng-template>
<app-menu>
```

Expected `<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef"></ng-template>` to contain

```
<ng-template>Item 1</ng-template>
<ng-template>Item 2</ng-template>
```

but it is empty.

> Replying to @Ricardo solution

I tried your `update`. It was empty as well.

Parent:

```
<app-childcomponent top-left-menu>
    <ng-template>Item 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template>Item 2</ng-template>
</app-childcomponent>
```

Child:

```
<ng-content select="[top-left-menu]"></ng-content>
```

**Also I also tried passing `ng-template` to `ng-content` but `Print ME!` did not get rendered. It was empty. It seems like `ng-template` dont go into `ng-content`?**

Parent:

```
<app-childcomponent [contextMenuSubject]="contextmenuSubject">
    <ng-template>Print ME!</ng-template>
</app-childcomponent>
```

Child:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Comment: If you send it as input param, then you should use NgTemplateOutlet to dynamically create component from template. What was your result?

Comment: I sent it as `input` param and receive as Input()myTemplate type of ElementRef and attempt to draw it with {{ myTemplate }}. I guess this is wrong X.X

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/
Easy explaination of ng-template and ngTemplateOutlet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can declare in your child component a default template with the property *ngTemplateOutlet* so you can bind a custom one from the parent component

```
<ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template || defaultTemplate"></ng-template>

<ng-template #defaultTemplate let-item="item">
    {{item}}
</ng-template>
```

you should expose *template* like a variable so the parent component can be used to inject the custom template.

the parent component should look like this

```
<child-component [template]="customTemplate" ></child-component>
 <ng-template #customTemplate let-item="item">
      {{item.name}}
 </ng-template>
```

> Other solution

In your child component, you can declare the ng-content like this:

```
 <ng-content select="[top-left-menu]"></ng-content>
```

then In your parent component, you can use his reference in this way:

```
<custom-super-component top-left-menu></custom-super-component>
```

your custom html/component will be placed in the position of your ng-content

Comment: Hi sounds great! Just curious if there any way to put the `template` inside the `child-component` tag? <child-component> or any cleaner way to do this?

Comment: @Zainu you can use <ng-content > tag to do it , declare this tag with a name and then refer from the parent component this ng-content tag in the html template that you want to put inside

Comment: hi, I have tried in chilldcomponent `<ng-content [ngTemplateOutlet]="customTemplate"></ng-content>` and ` @ContentChild(TemplateRef) customTemplate: TemplateRef<any>` . In parentcomponent `<child-component>
    <ng-template>Item 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template>Item 2</ng-template>
</child-component>`

Comment: I have updated with `Replying to @Ricardo solution` above ^